# How to compute only the diagonal of a matrix product in Octave?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, matrix-multiplication, diagonal

Is there a way in Octave to compute and store only the diagonal of a matrix product?

Basically like doing: `vector = diag(A*B);`

I don't care about any of the values of `A*B` except those on the diagonal. The matrix sizes are around `80k x 12` and `12 x 80k`, so even if I didn't care about the speed/extra memory it simply wont fit in RAM.

Strange, since Octave is a package for huge data sets and diagonals are very important, so it should be possible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first element in the diagonal is the scalar product of the first row of A with the first column of B. The second element in the diagonal is the scalar product of the second row of A with the second column of B.

In other words:

```
vector = sum(A.*B',2);
```

Comment: I see you made good use of the 5 minute grace period for editing. ;)

Comment: I'm glad the grace period exists. I seem to only see my major mistakes  once I hit submit. :)

Answer (score 11):

This is how you could do it in MATLAB (probably similar to Octave syntax):

```
vector = sum(A.*B',2);
```

This will compute only the resulting diagonal of the operation `A*B` as a column vector `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

actually I think it's the dot product of the first row of A with the first *column* of B... the second diagonal element is the dot product of the second row and the second column... etc