# octave: efficiency of using trace()?

Tags: octave

Suppose I have two 5000 x 1000 matrices, A and B. Will octave compute `trace(A*B')` efficiently, i.e. in a way that only requires 5000 inner products as opposed to 5000*5000 inner products most of which will not be used?

And, what if the argument to `trace` is more complicated, i.e.: `trace(A*B' + C*D')`? Does that change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trace(A*B')` will compute the complete matrix product before using `trace()`.

A more efficient approach would be `sum(sum(A.*conj(B),2))`. The inner sum computes the [diagonal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301076/1023843) of the resulting matrix.

A probably even more efficient approach would be doing both sums in one step via `sum((A.*conj(B))(:)).

`trace(A*B' + C*D')` would be computed efficiently by `sum((A.*conj(B) + C.*conj(D))(:))`.

Answer (score 1):

No, the product will be evaluated before the call to trace(). One efficient implementation would be to manually compute only the diagonal terms of that matrix multiply and then sum them  `sum(sum(diag(A) .* diag(B)));` for your second example `sum(sum(diag(A) .* diag(B) + diag(C) .* diag(D)))`

Note that you can shorten both expressions slightly and possibly gain a bit of speed at the loss of readability and Matlab compatibility like so: `sum((diag(A) .* diag(B))(:));`