# compact/efficient replacement for diag(X V X^T)?

Tags: r, linear-algebra

When making predictions for a linear statistical model we usually have a model matrix `X` of predictors corresponding to the points at which we want to make predictions; a vector of coefficients `beta`; and a variance-covariance matrix `V`.  Computing the predictions is just `X %*% beta`.  The most straightforward way to compute the *variances* of the predictions is

```
diag(X %*% V %*% t(X))
```

or slightly more efficiently

```
diag(X %*% tcrossprod(V,X))
```

However, this is very inefficient, because it constructs an n*n matrix when all we really want is the diagonal. I know I could write some Rcpp-loopy thing that would compute just the diagonal terms, but I'm wondering if there is an existing linear algebra trick in R that will nicely do what I want ... (if someone wants to write the Rcpp-loopy thing for me as an answer I wouldn't object, but I'd prefer a pure-R solution)

FWIW `predict.lm` seems to do something clever by multiplying `X` by the inverse of the R component of the QR-decomposition of the `lm`; I'm not sure that's always going to be available, but it might be a good starting point (see [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/0f07757ad10ca31251b28a2c332812e63c0acf38/src/library/stats/R/lm.R#L746-L756))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along the lines of this [Octave/Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301046/how-to-compute-only-the-diagonal-of-a-matrix-product-in-octave) question, for two matrices `A` and `B`, we can use the use the fact that the `nth` diagonal entry of `AB` will be the product of the `nth` row of `A` with the `nth` column of `B`.  We can naively extend that to the case of three matrices, `ABC`.  I have not considered how to optimize in the case where `C=A^T`, but aside from that, this code looks like promising speedup:

```r
start_time <- Sys.time()

A=matrix(1:1000000, nrow = 1000, ncol = 1000)
B=matrix(1000000:1, nrow = 1000, ncol = 1000)

# Try one of these two
res=diag(A %*% B %*% t(A)) # ~0.47s
res=rowSums(A * t(B %*% t(A))) # ~0.27s

end_time <- Sys.time()

print(end_time - start_time)
```

Using `tcrossprod` did not appear to accelerate the results when I ran this code.  However, just using the row-sum-dot-product approach appears to be a lot more efficient already, at least on this silly example, which *suggests* (though I'm not sure) that `rowSums` is *not* computing the full intermediate matrices before returning the diagonal entries, as I'd expect happens with `diag`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is more computationally efficient.  It would also be interesting to think about memory use, but this answer is definitely good enough for a check-mark ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how efficient this is,

1. Find U such that `V = U %*% t(U)`; this is possible since V is cov matrix.
2. `XU = X %*% U`
3. `result =  apply(XU, 1, function(x) sum(x^2))`

---

Demo

```
V <- cov(iris[, -5])
X <- as.matrix(iris[1:5, -5])
```

Using SVD

```
svd_v <- svd(V)
U <- svd_v$u %*% diag(sqrt(svd_v$d))
XU = X %*% U
apply(XU, 1, function(x) sum(x^2))
#       1        2        3        4        5 
#41.35342 39.36286 35.42369 38.25584 40.30839
```

Another approach - this isn't also going to be faster than @davewy's

```
U <- chol(V)
XU = (X %*% U)^2
rowSums(XU)
```

Comment: Time complexity of an SVD algorithm will be a lot more expensive than matrix multiplication (closer to O(n^3) than O(n^2), especially if you're asking for the full SVD), so I'm worried that will have scalability problems.  See e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161252/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-truncated-svd for some discussion.

Comment: don't know how Cholesky decomposition compares -- that's probably what I would have done instead of SVD.  (This gives more of a clue of what `predict.lm` is doing - since the QR decomposition is already stored in the `lm` object, inverting the (triangular) `R` component is cheap ...

Comment: I agree SVD may not be the best method - I main point is that if there is a method to get `U` fast, then the remaining approach could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found `emulator::quad.diag()`, which is just

```r
colSums(crossprod(M, Conj(x)) * x)
```

This is **slightly** better than @davewy's solution (although the overall differences are less than I thought they would be anyway).

```r
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(full=diag(A %*% B %*% t(A)), 
               davewy=rowSums(A * t(B %*% t(A))), 
               emu = quad.diag(A,B))
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
   full 32.76241 35.49665 39.51683 37.63958 41.46561 57.41370   100   c
 davewy 22.74787 25.06874 28.42179 26.97330 29.68895 45.38188   100  b 
    emu 17.68390 20.21322 23.59981 22.09324 24.80734 43.60953   100 a
```